# CakePHP view file via Media Views doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have CakePHP 1.3 and I have an action that is supposed to view a file, the file maybe a .pdf, .doc, .... or any document, but I get a blank page instead.

code sample:

```
public function view_attachments($attachment_id){
        $attachment = $this->get_attachment($attachment_id);
        if($attachment){
            $path = pathinfo($attachment['EmailAttachment']['file']);
            $this->view = 'Media';
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $params = array(
                'id' => $path['basename'],
                'name' => $path['filename'],              
                'download' => false,
                'mimeType'=> $this->Common->get_mime_content_type($path['basename']),          
                'extension' => strtolower($path['extension']),  // must be lower case              
                'path' => APP . $path['dirname'] . DS   // don't forget terminal 'DS'       
            );       
            $this->set($params);
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas? Please advise.

Comment: Can you add the debug() for $params? Verify your paths are correct. A 404 error from a media view is usually actually triggered BY the media view when it cannot find a file in question.

Answer (score 0):

check that media.ctp file must be blank... to get proper output...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checking on my own working code, the only difference I see is

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Of course your not supposed to have a "view_attachments.ctp" file.

Be aware that browser's can't open ".doc" natively. So even if you want him to display it, he will offer you to download it.

```
function download($id) {

    $data = $this->OdmPieceJointe->read(null, $id);
    $path = pathinfo($data['OdmPieceJointe']['fichier']);

    $this->view = 'Media';
    $params = array(
        'id' => $path['basename'],
        'name' => $path['filename'],
        'download' => false,
        'extension' => $path['extension'],
        'path' => 'uploads/',
        ); 

    $this->set($params);

}
```

Comment: I also tried this, to remove $this->autoRender=false; and making sure not to have a view file for it, then I get a Not Found screen.

Comment: Hum, just two others ideas : - Removing the 'mimetype' line - Putting a hard 'path'

Answer (score 0):

maybe :

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```